# Workflow 2010 Weird Bug

Tags: workflow, infopath

So i have a question about this weird bug. I have this:
[image]

As you can see it compares Current Item:(BLANK) not equal to an item that doesn't exist in the form anymore. What this is doing, I'm assuming from the results, is running anyways cause they don't equal.

My question is, does comparing a blank Current item != "field that doesn't exist" produce a true statement?

FYI i didnt write this.

I also have this and the if statement comes out to be true. I'm completely lost. How does "Current Item: equal Contract" even run? (Contract is a radio button btw)

[image]

Comment: The `If condition` is logically not correct. Can you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti I just want to know if it will do the task in the if statement. I never wrote this and were just deleting this workflow.  I just wanted to know what Current Item:"Blank" does and what people use it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if statement is referencing a field that no longer exists in the list - that's what happens when you delete a field that is used in a workflow. It keeps the CurrentItem: but the field is missing. Same for the other lines inside that if.

It's trying to check to see if the 2 fields are equal - if they aren't, it does the email and then sets the Legal2 field to the missing field. LegalUser2 is probably a hidden field.

That's a usual technique to only send an email when a certain field is changed (in this example, some kind of people field)

The second one trying to see if it's a contract - the field was deleted. Might have been a choice field. Maybe a content type....

Comment: Thank you @robin-in-or for the response, but i don't believe LegalUser2 is a hidden field. Correct me if I'm wrong but don't the selectable fields in a workflow have to be found in "Property Promotion" in the Form Options. I cant find this field anywhere and its still an option in the workflow.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Infopath, but I believe you are right - you have to promote the field out to the list for workflow to get at it. I was talking about the basic list structure - hiding the field on the content type. Maybe look at the actual list content type from list settings, and see if the field was added there and hidden - totally separate from the InfoPath definition.

Comment: you where right. I looked into the document library settings and found all these fields listed that I never found on the form. I've never made a form or form library in this way but now i know. Thanks again!